# What are good general techniques to extract the last n bytes from a stream of input

Tags: algorithm, io, stream, language-agnostic

Assuming I have a binary stream of input bytes of unknown length that end with an identifiable EOF-like condition, what are some algorithms to extract the last, say 8 bytes and process them differently from the rest of the input?  Assume there are not any nice implementation specific features like seeking to the end, or rewinding the stream, or calling tac.  Assume input might be larger than the RAM so full-buffering would fail.

For the first bytes of a file or a field it's pretty easy: consume that many bytes and process them however you need to.  But for the last bytes the algorithms seem more error prone.

I've done this in the past by building a 2-segment circular buffer and only processing the oldest segment after it's confirmed EOF hasn't been reached.

```
while not end of STREAM
    read n bytes from STREAM and place in open segment
        set m to number of bytes actually read
    if end of STREAM
        o = n - m
        process first m bytes normally from older segment
        process last o bytes from older segment specially
        process first m bytes from newer segment specially
    else
        process n bytes from older segment normally
        declare older segment open
```

This isn't just full of corner cases, it's made of corner cases.
Are there any other algorithms for this that are a little safer from implementation errors?  Or is there a better way to do this algorithm?

Comment: How much memory are you allowed to use to solve this?

Comment: Assume not enough to hold the entire stream.  Some fixed amount.  The process should remain a streaming process with a contained memory footprint.
Using whole-output and whole-input buffers limits the useful size range by the size of RAM.  And not everything is a server or even a PC.

Comment: The general idea is to fill a buffer, and then process bytes from the buffer until either A) the buffer has only 8 unused bytes left, or B) the bytes left in the buffer are insufficient for normal processing. At that point, move the remaining bytes  to the beginning of the buffer, and refill the buffer.

Comment: So, similar to what I'm doing but with a linear buffer and copying instead of a segmented circular buffer.  Makes sense, getting rid of the extra complication of having a circular buffer would simplify the code into one problem instead of two.

Comment: Yes, that's right. One thing to be aware of is that buffer needs to be big enough so that the copies aren't a significant portion of the processing time. I used this technique for an HTTP server on an embedded system. HTTP headers consist of lines of text, where neither the length of a line, nor the number of lines is known in advance. I used a 1KB buffer, while assuming that an average line is about 40 bytes. That way, the code could process about 25 lines, then copy about 40 bytes and refill the buffer. So roughly two bytes worth of copy overhead for an average line.